# MonoRail ActiveRecord/NHibernate calculation in where clause

Tags: nhibernate, activerecord, castle-monorail

I'm trying to get businesses within a certain number of miles of a user, using a formula to get the distance between the lat/long of the business and the lat/long of the user. Here is the code:

```
var criteria = DetachedCriteria.For<Core.Models.Business>();      criteria.Add(Restrictions.Le(String.Format(@"(3959*acos(cos(radians({0}))*cos(radians(Latitude))*cos(radians(Longitude)-radians({1}))
                    +sin(radians({0}))*sin(radians(Latitude))))", coordinates.Latitude, coordinates.Longitude), radiusInMiles));
```

The problem is that ActiveRecord/NHibernate's Restrictions.Le method expects a property name for the first parameter so I can't put a formula in there. How would I do something like this?

Thanks!
Justin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `Expression.Sql`.  A couple of examples:

- [NHibernate Query that simulates SQL Replace Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/899094/nhibernate-query-that-simulates-sql-replace-function)
- [NHibernate and MySql Keywords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2660035/nhibernate-and-mysql-keywords)

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately Restrictions.Sql doesn't exist, perhaps that was just in older versions?

Comment: @Justin: sorry, it's actually called Expression.Sql